# response type blob but getting xml data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I have a angularjs function to call to a API. API returning an image one time.it is returning a xml another time. I can show returned image if I set response type blob as follow

```
$http({
        url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
        method: "POST",
        responseType: "blob",
        data: {
            "Req": req
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Username': aUser,
            'X-Password': aPass,
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
        dataType: "xml"
    }).success(function(data, status) {
       console.log(data);
    }
```

console.log printing blob object. But when API returns xml content it is also returning as a blob object. I tried to get xml content of the blob but couldn't find a way :(. Can some one suggest me a way to get xml data from the blob object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. We can extract blob object using FileReader.

What I did was,

```
$http({
    url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
    method: "POST",
    responseType: "blob",
    data: {
        "Req": req
    },
    headers: {
        'X-Username': aUser,
        'X-Password': aPass,
        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
    dataType: "xml"
}).success(function(data, status) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
         console.log(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(data);
}
```